# Unfamiliar symbols in sets & relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

What is the sign that looks like intersection called and what does it mean? I understand the 1st sign means all the elements of of all the sets.

[image]

Comment: `the sign that looks like intersection` I would venture that it does indeed mean "*intersection*".

Comment: I have intersection sign in a previous page.. it's way smaller and it's mentioned as intersection. This is way larger.

Comment: They explain what $\bigcap S$ and $\bigcup S$ mean in the paragraph. If you read that, you should have your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text tells you.

$$
\bigcap S
$$

is the set of elements from your universe that is in *all* of the sets in $S$.

I'm not aware that the symbol is "called" anything in particular, it's just a large version of the normal intersection symbol. The LaTeX - and MathJax - which for this site is more relevant - command to produce it is `\bigcap`

This usage of the symbol is a bit different from what I have normally seen which is
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_k
$$
which means the intersection of all the $A_k$ sets with $k$ between $1$ and $n$ (both inclusive), which could informally be written as:
$$
A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n.
$$

The difference being that in the notation you presented $S$ is a set of sets and $\bigcap S$ is just a set. In "my" notation, both the $A_k$'s and $\bigcap A_k$ (note the exclusion of limits, which is also seen, and just mean "all of them") is a set. In finite cases you can of course define the set of all the $A_k$'s and use "your" notation, but
$$
\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k \overset{meaning}{=}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} A_k
$$
is also seen, and then "your" notation becomes hard to deal with.

Comment: what's the difference? the 1st sign means all elements in all of the sets.

Comment: sorry I meant difference between the intersection symbol and the one looking like a union symbol?

Comment: @33ted The one looking like a union symbol is a union symbol, the same way the one that looks like an intersection simple is an intersection symbol.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually the alternative formulation for $\bigcup S$ would be $\bigcup_{A\in S}A$. Unlike $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k$, that also works for uncountable collections of sets. Also, is there really anyone defining it as limit? Indeed, defining the limit without union and intersection, and then defining those from the limit seems harder than defining union and intersection directly, and then defining the limit based on union and intersection. And of course defining as limit again restricts it to countable intersections; also, you'd have to prove separately that reordering does not change the limit.